# How to update twitter status from my ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

I am trying to update my status from my asp.net web page.

Below is my code; but its not updating.
Please check my code and reply back.

```
protected void btnTwitt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string twitterMsg = txtShout.Text;
    OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens();
    tokens.AccessToken = "My Access Token";
    tokens.AccessTokenSecret = "My Access Token Secret here";
    tokens.ConsumerKey = "My Consumer Key";
    tokens.ConsumerSecret = "My Consumer Secrete here";
    TwitterResponse<Twitterizer.TwitterStatus> tweetResponse = 
        Twitterizer.TwitterStatus.Update(tokens, twitterMsg);
    lblTwitMsg.Text = "Your have shout successfully on http://twitter.com/" + "";
}
```

Comment: Check [C# code to publish, delete, retrieve tweets using oauth](http://coderbuddy.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/c-code-to-publish-delete-retrieve-tweets-using-oauth/), **Note -** it is my blog post

Answer (score 1):

The code below worked for me:

```
protected void Tweet_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

    string Twet = txtTweet.InnerText;
    ViewState["twe"] = Twet.ToString();
    string Twttxt = ViewState["twe"].ToString();



    OAuthTokens a = new OAuthTokens();
    a.ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret;
    a.ConsumerKey = consumerKey;
    a.AccessToken = ViewState[" AccessKey "].ToString();
    a.AccessTokenSecret = ViewState["  AccessSecrt"].ToString();

    TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> tweet = TwitterStatus.Update(a, "" + Twttxt + "");


    txtTweet.Value = "";
    DataList1.Visible = true;
    string nm = ViewState[" Twitter_id"].ToString();
    TimeLineLoad(nm);//function used to fill my tweets in datalist


}
```

Comment: http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2010/05/tweet-posting-from-aspnet-using-oauth.html -check out this too

Comment: this code isnt complete. the error is probably related to getting the token information (accesstoken and secret).

Answer (score 1):

I face error on given line

TwitterResponse tweet = TwitterStatus.Update(a, "" + Twttxt + "");

Error  3   The type or namespace name 'TwitterResponse' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)